# Stateless REST API with CSRF and XSS protection

Tags: rest, security, jwt, xss, csrf

Is it possible to protect stateless REST API from both XSS and CSRF attacks?

Currently, I'm using JWT token stored in *secure/httpOnly* cookie for stateless authentication. This should protect the API from most common XSS attack: stealing cookies with XSS-injected JavaScript and sending them to the attacker.

However, this doesn't protect the API from CSRF attack, where attacker would trick the authenticated user to follow a link to the particular web API call to actuate adverse transaction on behalf of the victim. How could I protect the API from this attack **without introducing server side state**?

Also, is it true XSS vulnerability would inheritedly allow CSRF type attack in the following scenario: Injected JavaScript would retrieve CSRF token from the client side state, DOM or the browser storage and prepare a malicious ajax call to the server. Browser would still automatically include the httpOnly cookie for the same origin request. Is there a way to get protected from this other than protecting from the XSS vulnerability in the first place?

Comment: CRSF Attacks mainly target cookies, as these could be sent to the server if carrying out a CSRF attack. So a relatively easy counter-measure is to use a special header with every API request. This header does not even need to carry a token, something like: `"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"` actually should be enough.

Comment: In addition, cookies can be secured using the httpOnly Flag which prevents any attacker from reading such cookies. Hovever these must be set by the server, and while the combination of those two measures should be fairly secure (of course you still have to protect against various XSS attack vectors) it is not stateless, as then you need a classic session management on the server. I have exactly the same problem, and haven't found a good solution to make all of that really stateless, since we also need to secure static assets like html5 video as well. If you have found anything, let me know!

Answer (score 3):

#### Stateless anti-forgery tokens

The first question is about preventing [CSRF](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf) without server-side state. The current approach for stateless anti-forgery tokens is the [double submit cookie](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#double-submit-cookie) pattern.

CSRF attacks depend on the browser automatically sending the API's own cookies back to it, regardless of where the request originated. The attacker doesn't have or need access to the cookie contents. They only need to trick the user into loading malicious HTML. The double cookie pattern adds a new requirement: the attacker must know and separately send the contents of the anti-forgery cookie.

There are ways for an attacker to overwrite the anti-forgery cookie with their own. So you may want to look at some [additional security hardening](https://owasp.org/www-pdf-archive/David_Johansson-Double_Defeat_of_Double-Submit_Cookie.pdf) for this approach. Especially HMAC signing the anti-forgery token to prevent token substitution. Using HSTS and the `__Host` cookie prefix to ensure transport security and proper cookie scope. And having the client provide the anti-forgery token in a custom header.

The custom header ensures the request must be sent from JS, since HTML-tag-based CSRF attacks cannot set custom headers. Being sent from JS also triggers additional protections. For cross-origin requests it triggers [SOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) on the browser and [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) validation on the server. The server can also do basic [Origin validation](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#verifying-origin-with-standard-headers).

Regarding the scope of CSRF attacks, here is a note from the OWASP CSRF link at the top.

> Forcing the victim to retrieve data doesn’t benefit an attacker because the attacker doesn’t receive the response, the victim does. As such, CSRF attacks target state-changing requests.

#### XSS question

Yes, an [XSS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) attack could happen that way. Once a malicious script is loaded into JS, it has free reign to use anything accessible to Javascript. Including app code/memory, browser storage, and cookies. Even though HttpOnly cookies are not readable, they can still be sent in requests. A non-targeted attack might look for key data in locations used by popular frameworks. And might try to probe for popular/discoverable API frameworks on the server. A targeted attack means the attacker studied your system and crafted a custom payload for it.

The primary vector for XSS is unsanitized external data (user input, database values, etc.). To prevent XSS, check out these [guidelines from OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html). Of note is that front-end frameworks like Angular, React, Svelte, Vue, and others have built-in XSS protection. Because they sanitize data before rendering it. Example: an attacker enters an HTML string into an input. When it is later displayed, these frameworks HTML-encode the string. So left and right angle brackets are replaced with `&lt;` and `&gt;` and so on. This causes the browser to evaluate the string as text instead of runnable HTML. But you can still [mess it up](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#bonus-rule-4-properly-use-modern-js-frameworks) in [different ways](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/react-xss-guide-examples-and-prevention/#escape-hatches-in-react-can-cause-an-xss-attack) if careless.

XSS attacks can also come from external resources. Maybe a compromised CDN or NPM script. If your deployed code takes dependencies on NPM libraries, pay extra attention to NPM audit warnings. One attack pattern is to attach a small loader (easier to go unnoticed), which will fetch attack payloads at runtime. A [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) policy can help prevent this. Specify an allowed list of resources -- your app assets and API URLs -- and block all others. CSP can also prevent data exfiltration.

#### For both CSRF and XSS

For attacks on your API, you can additionally employ server-side mitigations. IP-based throttling / temporary bans, unusual activity grey-listing and alerting, etc.

For especially sensitive operations, one strategy is to use an escalated authorization. This could take the form of requiring the user to re-authenticate or use a 2nd factor like a one-time password. This can block automated attacks since it requires active user intervention.

To mitigate attackers using existing escalated authorizations (which may also be in a cookie or app memory), they can have short expirations and be limited to specific operations. To go even further, the approved operations + relevant data can be signed. This will prevent malicious scripts from reusing an escalation to execute the same kind of operation with different data. Even further, these sensitive operations can be [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). So if an attacker does resend already-executed operations, they will not cause any additional changes in the system.

#### Zooming out

Try to engineer your systems to be as uninteresting as possible to hackers. Use trusted external services for sensitive needs like credit cards and credentials. Ideally (from a security perspective) the hacking risk would be reduced to just data vandalism/loss. So in the worst case that a breach happens, it would have little long-term impact. And it could be recovered with common practices, including routinely tested backups. And then further mitigations added for the specific attacks used.

Tread especially carefully with user-to-user interaction. Since this adds more targets and pivot points for hackers -- your user base. The most security-conscious eyes should be on these pieces. Not only for technical dangers like user-to-user XSS attacks, but also social ones. Human weaknesses are the most well-known and easiest to exploit.

Lastly, there is no sense investing in mitigations which have low risk/consequences in your situation. So do not take everything here as a requirements checklist. It's not a complete list anyway. Focus on your biggest risks first. Reevaluate periodically.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a token (e.g. a UUID) and put it into the jwt token as well as send it back to the client. Then the client sends it during every each request in a header. Then the server can compare the token in the header and the token in the jwt token to make sure the request comes from the client who was aunthenticated.